# One signal - create segment to push to recent location

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I would like to, via OneSignal REST API :

- filter the push to users in a certain location (as in the [doc](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#section-how-do-i-send-messages-to-users-by-location-)) but it lacks sample code/relevant routes. The steps would be :

  - store tags for users (documented [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/playersid-1), this is fine)
  - creating a segment (I don't see this in the docs)
  - push by filtering by segment (this is covered [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-create-notification))
- Similarly I would like to be able to filter the push to users that visited a location in a certain date range (ex. last week, last month...). I am not completely sure this is possible using only OneSignal.

The minimum I would need is how to create a segment with OneSignal.

Edit : looks like there is a way in the dashboard, but I need to do it programmatically. [image: dashboard screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I help work on OneSignal) OneSignal does not support programmatically targeting by a location at this time but we're planning on adding support for this in the near future.

One way to do some of this until then would be to provide the name or position of a location as tags. For instance you could use the tags `lat=41.123, lon=55.331`, then target users programmatically where the tags are greater than and less than the ranges you specify.

OneSignal does not provide built-in functionality to target by historical locations and we do not plan to add support for this, but you may be able to use tags to achieve your desired result.

Note that OneSignal does allow you to target by Player ID, so you could always store your users' Player IDs in your own system and do the calculation of who should receive a notification on your own.